# Style part of svg when using it via use

Tags: css, svg

Is it possible style an svg icon embedded using the svg-use syntax only within a certain item?
I can easily style the icon in general, but I would like to style a part of an svg icon when the icon is used within the nav-item.

This is what I tried without any success.

```
// css
.nav-item .part1{
 opacity: 0.5;
}
```

When using the svg like this:

```
<svg id="svg_sprite" style="display: none;">
  <defs>
    <g id="icon">
      <polygon points="476.5,379.778 401.167,..."></polygon>
      <polygon class="page1" points="221,379.768 85.334,..."></polygon>
    </g>
  </defs>
</svg>

<li class="nav-item">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 512 512" class="icon">
    <use xlink:href="#icon"></use>
  </svg>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no. You cannot style an element based on whether it has been referenced by a `<use>` or not.  The SVG spec specifically says this.  The reason is that the content referenced by the `<use>` is only a "conceptual clone" and is not actually part of the DOM.

http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#UseElement

Comment: Darn, I was afraid this might be the case, thanks for clarifying.